# How to update array of object in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out how to change state in my app correctly. For example, I want change 'modalStatus' key of a particular post to true, what should I write in my showModal function? I have the following data-structure:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  posts: [
    {
      'author': 'Adolf Hitler',
      'img': 'http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/images/hitler1.jpg',
      'content': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam deleniti incidunt consectetur omnis molestiae exercitationem accusamus nostrum quia libero esse maxime aliquid ducimus, placeat rem commodi. Animi cum aut odit.',
      modalStatus: false
    },
    {
      'author': 'Iosif Stalin',
      'img': 'http://xn--h1aagokeh.xn--p1ai/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/46432404.jpg',
      'content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam deleniti incidunt consectetur omnis molestiae exercitationem accusamus nostrum quia libero esse maxime aliquid ducimus, placeat rem commodi. Animi cum aut odit.',
      modalStatus: false
    },
    {
      'author': 'Napoleon Bonapard',
      'img':'http://cdn.history.com/sites/2/2015/04/hith-6-things-you-should-know-about-napoleon-E.jpeg',
      'content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam deleniti incidunt consectetur omnis molestiae exercitationem accusamus nostrum quia libero esse maxime aliquid ducimus, placeat rem commodi. Animi cum aut odit.',
      modalStatus: false
    },
    {
      'author': 'Vladimir Putin',
      'img':'http://realnienovosti.com/images/148795554214.jpg',
      'content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam deleniti incidunt consectetur omnis molestiae exercitationem accusamus nostrum quia libero esse maxime aliquid ducimus, placeat rem commodi. Animi cum aut odit.',
      modalStatus: false
    }
  ]
};
```

And function that is responsible for changing the state:

```
showModal () {
 this.setState(do something)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this, pass a index to this function whose value you want to edit,

```
showModal (index) {
   var posts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.posts));
   posts[index].modalStatus = true;
   this.setState({posts});
}
```

Check the [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state).

Or You could use the [update immutability helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) for this:

```
this.setState({
    posts: update(this.state.posts, {0: {modalStatus: {$set: true}}})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
showModal () {
  var item = this.state.posts[0];
  item.modalStatus = true;
  this.setState({});
}
```

After that - React will re-render your component according to new state object.